# Xcode Unity build: app freezes and has some errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

The app successfully built to Google Play as well as WebGL. I've tried switching all kinds of build settings in Unity, which leads me to believe there's something wrong in Xcode.

[image]

I also get these:
    dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
    ->  0x1200ed088 <+0>: brk    #0x3

```
dyld`_dyld_start:
0x1200ed000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
0x1200ed004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x1200ed008 <+8>:   movz   x0, #0
0x1200ed00c <+12>:  movz   x1, #0
0x1200ed010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-16]!
0x1200ed014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
0x1200ed018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #16               ; =16 
0x1200ed01c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x1200ed020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #8]
0x1200ed024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #16              ; =16 
0x1200ed028 <+40>:  adrp   x4, -1
0x1200ed02c <+44>:  add    x4, x4, #0                ; =0 
0x1200ed030 <+48>:  adrp   x3, 48
0x1200ed034 <+52>:  ldr    x3, [x3, #3320]
0x1200ed038 <+56>:  sub    x3, x4, x3
0x1200ed03c <+60>:  mov    x5, sp
0x1200ed040 <+64>:  bl     0x1200ed08c               ;      dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long,         macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
`->  0x1200ed044 <+68>:  mov    x16, x0
0x1200ed048 <+72>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x1200ed04c <+76>:  cmp    x1, #0                    ; =0 
0x1200ed050 <+80>:  b.ne   0x1200ed05c               ; <+92>
0x1200ed054 <+84>:  add    sp, x28, #8               ; =8 
0x1200ed058 <+88>:  br     x16
0x1200ed05c <+92>:  mov    x30, x1
0x1200ed060 <+96>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #8]
0x1200ed064 <+100>: add    x1, x28, #16              ; =16 
0x1200ed068 <+104>: add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x1200ed06c <+108>: add    x2, x2, #8                ; =8 
0x1200ed070 <+112>: mov    x3, x2
0x1200ed074 <+116>: ldr    x4, [x3]
0x1200ed078 <+120>: add    x3, x3, #8                ; =8 
0x1200ed07c <+124>: cmp    x4, #0                    ; =0 
0x1200ed080 <+128>: b.ne   0x1200ed074               ; <+116>
0x1200ed084 <+132>: br     x16
```

Any ideas what is the problem? All tutorials and guides I look at just fill in code signing and all that, and launch the project like nothing is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Post the screenshot of your player setting tab in unity for iOS

Comment: Done, edited into the main post.

Comment: What version of Unity? What version of Xcode?

Comment: 5.3.5f1 Unity | 7.3.1 Xcode.
I believe that would be the newest version of both.

Comment: building on original device or Simulator.?

Comment: Tried both. Simulator takes about 3-4 minutes to build, and device takes 20 sec or so, so I tend to prefer the device. But yes, both have the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by changing scripting backend from **Mono2x** to **IL2CPP** in the Unity settings for iOS. Also set the architecture to universal. No idea why this works, but I won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried build with "Device SDK" instead of "Simulator SDK" in player setting? I found an answer [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1075087/view.html)

Comment: Indeed I have, I've tried both. Sadly, it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: @Blobbey My friend tells me that it's probably coz the framework you added urself lacks files (maybe broken)

Comment: After your comment, I wondered if this was actually the case. In my Unity project, I had GameJolt api and Unity Ads. Removed them both, and that seemed to remove the warnings on my first picture. Sadly, the dyld errors and freezing is still there.